# Can Skarner's Ultimate (Impale) cause a friendly turret to switch focus away from champion he has Impaled?

Tags: league-of-legends

To clarify, while watching the ggClassic tonight we saw a Skarner get turret-dove by two enemies and when he ulted the one who had Turret Aggro, the turret seemed to switch to the OTHER enemy champion, which allowed the initial diver to survive.

Can someone confirm or deny if this is the case? Do you think that it is a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in that case Skarner's ult cancelled Jax's auto attack animation so the tower agro didn't proc on Jax and went to Shyvana since she was in front. But generally the tower agro will stay on the person that Skarner ulted.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a lot more sense. It seemed to crazy to be true.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, the things happened there (I think):
Two enemies tower dive, tower started attacking the one who came into tower-range 1st, but the champ that got focused 1st had no time to attack the defending champion - Skarner. Skarner ulti'd the 1st champ and then the 2nd champion came and hit Skarner so the tower changed focus to the champion that hit the defender